# pd Fill NAN with increasing incremental Value python

Tags: python, nan

Hi I am trying to do an incremental increase on the data I have for NaN values
for example:

| Day | Reding |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN |
| 2 | 2.5 |
| 3 | NaN |
| 4 | NaN |
| 5 | NaN |
| 6 | 3.9 |
| 7 | NaN |
| 8 | 3.4 |

To this:

| Day | Reading |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.5 |
| 2 | 2.5 |
| 3 | 2.85 |
| 4 | 3.2 |
| 5 | 3.55 |
| 6 | 3.9 |
| 7 | 3.65 |
| 8 | 3.4 |

Comment: The word you're looking for is _interpolation_. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html

Comment: @PranavHosangadi,  to get the reading for day=1 would be extrapolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pranav mentioned, you can try using interpolation

```
from cmath import nan
import pandas

dataframe = pandas.DataFrame({'Day': list(range(1,8+1)), 'Reding': [nan, 2.5, nan, nan, nan, 3.9, nan, 3.4]})
dataframe.Reding = dataframe.Reding.interpolate()
print(dataframe)
```

Output

```
   Day  Reding
0    1     NaN
1    2    2.50
2    3    2.85
3    4    3.20
4    5    3.55
5    6    3.90
6    7    3.65
7    8    3.40
```